# How to stop a class from being clickable in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have multiple images which when click imcrease in size. Also when clicked the page is dimmed and a close button is added. Currently an multiple images can be clicked one after the other and they all enlarge but in my function I'd like to stop the others from being clicked after one of them is. The when the close button is pressed they can all be clicked again (But I'm not worried about that for now).

I tried using removeEventListener but had no success.
Any hep would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="product">
   <div class="image-container">
   <img src="assets/home-bg.jpg" class="thumbnail">
   </div>    
</div>

<div class="product">
    <div class="image-container">
    <img src="assets/enchilada.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    </div>    
</div>

<div class="product">
     <div class="image-container">
     <img src="assets/quesadilla.jpg" class="thumbnail">
     </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1200;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');

images.forEach(function(image) {
  image.addEventListener('click', enlarge);
});

function enlarge(e) {
  var image = e.target;
  var interval;
  var height = 200;
  var width = 200;
  var z = $(this).css("z-index"); //Obtain the current z-index of the image which has been clicked

    $(this).css("z-index", z + 10);  //increase the z-index of just the image which has been selected by 10

    $("#close-button").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#dimmed-cover").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#close-button").click(function () {
        $("#close-button").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#dimmed-cover").css("visibility", "hidden");
        });

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    height += 6.666;
    width += 6.666;

    if(height >= 600 && width >= 600) {
      height = 600;
      width = 600;
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    image.style.height = height + 'px';
    image.style.width = width + 'px';
  }, 16.667);
}

});
```

Comment: why do you use plain javascript commands if you are allready using jquery?  .bind and .unbind will help you by the way

Comment: Have you tried just using a shared variable? Something like `imageOpen = true;` when the `enlarge` method starts executing?

Comment: @Alpha No I haven't, but sounds promising, how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: @Alpha I know how to disable a button but not a class which has an event listener attached to it

Comment: @EthanBristow As for the variable, you would just declare it outside of the event, and give it the right value when the event executes. regarding the event listener, you seemed to be on the right track by removing the listener -- would you mind including that part of the code? Somebody may be able to spot what was wrong with it.

Comment: @Alpha I simply added image.removeEventListener('click', enlarge); but Ihave a feeling it wasn't working becuase it was only removing the listener for the image I'd already enlarged?

Comment: @EthanBristow You're right -- that seems correct, and your deduction too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle a class on the parent body or html which will help append a global class. In your javascript `enlarge` function, you can add something like:

```
$('body').toggleClass('image-no-click');
```

And in your css, have something like:

```
.image-no-click .thumbnail { pointer-events: none }
```

Comment: Thanks @rynomite this is what I was looking for, pointer-events: none  wasn't something I was aware of/used before :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a variable Imgop and on the enlarge event set it to false.

then add basic if statements to the parts of code you do not want to work while the image is enlarged.